# how to map java.time.Duration to XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, java-8, java-time

I have a bean with the datatype:

```
private java.time.Duration duration
```

the class attribute is set like that:

```
object.setDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
```

I want to marshall my object to xml so that duration looks like that

```
<duration>PT2S</duration>
```

as defined [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)

As far as I understand, Jaxb uses [default binding data types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/bind.html) like:

```
xsd:duration    javax.xml.datatype.Duration
```

but in my bean I don't want to include any xml dependency.

I see the possibility of writing a wrapper where I can add a [XmlAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html), but I don't know how to transform java.time.Duration to javax.xml.datatype.Duration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out by searching around checking at the API's. Here is my code:

```
import java.time.Duration
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;

public class DurationAdapter extends XmlAdapter<javax.xml.datatype.Duration, Duration>
{
    @Override
    public Duration unmarshal(javax.xml.datatype.Duration v) throws Exception {
        return Duration.parse(v.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public javax.xml.datatype.Duration marshal(Duration v) throws Exception {
        return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newDuration(v.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. Java Time Duration doesn't contain years. `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text cannot be parsed to a Duration`

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. The javax.xml.datatype.Duration "P0Y0M0DT0H0M1S" can't be parsed by java.time.Duration. I have noticed the `javax.xml.datatype.Duration.toString` produces different output depending on the implementation, so it might work for some application but not for others.

Answer (score 1):

I found an implementation of this adapters on [GitHub](https://github.com/migesok/jaxb-java-time-adapters). In addition to `Duration` it has the other `java.time.*` types like `Instant` and `Period`.

The only downside is that the marshalling uses strings instead of the corresponding `javax.xml.datatype.*`.

Comment: I see, there is an improved version to mine: https://github.com/migesok/jaxb-java-time-adapters/blob/master/src/main/java/com/migesok/jaxb/adapter/javatime/DurationXmlAdapter.java